# Getting status code not working httpClient angular

Tags: angular

First i will say i am totally new to angular and reading the doc says to get response we should use {observe: response} so in my services i did this

```
createTruck(truck: Truck): Observable<number> {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl, JSON.stringify(truck), {observe: 'response'})
      .pipe(
        map(this.extractData),
        tap(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data))),
        catchError(this.handleError));

  }

updateTrucks(truck: Truck): Observable<Truck> {
    return this.http.put(this.baseUrl, JSON.stringify(truck), {observe: 'response'})
      .pipe(
      //  map(this.extractData),
       // tap(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data))),
        catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

I want my html to return a message successful or conflict by checking the status code, so i am using statuscode : number as var in component and *ngIf in html to check for status code value, here is my component and a bit of html  thank you for your assist

```
processForm() {

    this.processValidation = true;
    if (this.truckForm.invalid) {
      return; //Validation failed, exit from method.
    }

    // if we are here then all good
    this.preProcessConfigurations()

    let truckCode = this.truckForm.get('truckCode').value.trim();
    let date = this.truckForm.get('date').value.trim();
    let description = this.truckForm.get('descriptions').value.trim();


    if (this.truck.truckId == undefined) {
      let truck= new Truck(null, truckCode, date, description);

      this.truckService.createTruck(truck).subscribe((truck) => {

          this.router.navigate(['/trucks']);
        },
        error => {
          if(error){
            this.statusCode=error;
            console.log('error code'+ this.statusCode)
          }
        });

    }else {
      let truck= new Truck(this.truck.truckId, truckCode, date, description);

      this.truckService.updateTrucks(truck).subscribe((truck) => {

          this.router.navigate(['/trucks']);
        },
        error => {

          if(error){
            this.statusCode = error;
            console.log('error code'+ this.statusCode)
          }

        });

    }
  }
```

my html looks like this

```
 <br/>
              <div *ngIf="statusCode; else processing">
                <div *ngIf="statusCode === 400" [ngClass] = "'success'">
                  Truck already exists.
                </div>

                <div *ngIf="statusCode === 201" [ngClass] = "'success'">
                  Truck added successfully.
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="statusCode === 409" [ngClass] = "'success'">
                  Truck already exists.
                </div>
```

in console when when i post sucessfully i get no responseand when i tried to get a conflict  i get

```
webpack-internal:///./src/app/services/trucks/truck.service.ts:56 Http failure response for http://localhost:8088/trucks: 409 Conflict
```

This is my error handler and response

```
  private extractData(response: HttpResponse<Truck>) {
    const body = response;
    return body || {};
  }

  private handleError (error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    console.error(error.message || error);
    return Observable.throw(error.status);
  }
```

Comment: You can use a http interceptor to handle http response errors.

Comment: so i create this in my service ? can you show a bit of code and how i connect it to my html ?

Comment: Do you want to show a message according to http response status only in this component?

Comment: yes thats what i want

Comment: so i wanted to subscribe in a way that i get the status code and call it in html to get a response

Comment: Did you try returning only the erro from this? (without error.status)

`private handleError (error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    console.error(error.message || error);
    return Observable.throw(error);
  }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168843/discussion-between-anuradha-gunasekara-and-valik).